# NAPTR support for SLES

Tags: dns, sip, suse

Do you know if there is a library in SLES9 or SLES10 which support NAPTR queries for ENUM functionality?

The libadns doesn't support NAPTR. There are other libraries which support NAPTR queries but they aren't included in SLES.

Comment: Do you mean just sending NAPTR queries or also parsing them (a much more complicated task)?

Comment: Need to find a C library consists of an asynchronous DNS resolver (except Sofia Resolver) which supports DNS queries for NAPTR records (and SRV, A records) and parses the NAPTR records to the appropriate data fields: Order, Preference, Substitution expression, e.t.c.